# Save excel workbook with a user defined filename using VB.NET (What is wrong with this statement?)

Tags: vb.net, excel, save

VB.NET level:Beginner

On my interface user defines a name of the case in a textbox. I want to use this name as a filename for my excel workbook.

Is there any way to do this?

Following statement gives either no exception or error, but it is not doing what I want to do.

```
oWB.savecopyas("D:\"val(textbox1.text)".xlsx")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you need to concatenate the strings `oWB.savecopyas("D:\" & val(textbox1.text) & ".xlsx") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
oWB.savecopyas("D:\" & textbox1.text & ".xlsx")
```

Comment: You should probably also validate that the user is not entering things in the textbox that will cause issues. A "\" for instance.